# How to get the Memory details of the machine using the PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to get the memory details like Total RAM, core and OS details of the remote machine with the PostgreSQL query like we have in SQL server (sys.dm_os_sys_memory)?

If yes, kindly advise me the query.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the [system_stats](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/system_stats) extension, there is nothing built into the Postgres core.

The [PostgreSQL YUM repository](https://yum.postgresql.org/) provides pre-built RPM packages of that extension, but only for Postgres 10 or newer. But as Postgres 9.5 will be unsupported in about 5 months, you have to plan for an upgrade anyway